# How can I insert decimals into a number

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, oracle11g

I have a DB file that is exported from Oracle.  I'm using SQLite command line to convert a table in the DB file to a CSV so I can then import the data into MSSQL.  My problem is that the table I need has numbers for one field formatted as 3454336 and I need them formatted as 3454.336.  I need to basically insert a decimal before the last three digits when I create the CSV.  If there is a better way to do this in an automated fashion to get a CSV I'm open to it because I know I'm limited in what SQLLite command line can do.

```
sqlite3.exe -csv d:\temp\hourly-export.db "SELECT * FROM status" > d:\temp\status.csv
```

Comment: Do you know the last 3 digits are always decimals? You can just import your data in SQL Server (into a DECIMAL(18, 3) column) and then just divide the numbers by 1000.

Comment: Instead of * you should explicitly name the columns. Then for the column of numbers you simply divide by 1000.

Comment: It is always something simple!  I can easily divide by 1000 in SQL or when I program the page with CFML.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the column? Is it a number or a string?

Comment: How do I mark the best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQLite you can do it by splitting and inserting the dot:

```
select substr(colname, 1, length(colname) - 3) || '.' || substr(colname, -3) from status
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and keeps me from having to use code to format after the fact.  Thanks!